# Condition not working in Url Rewrite on IIS 10

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-10

I have an URL https://www.something.com?token=abcd2345
I want all the traffic to redirect to https://www.somethingelse.com?userToken=abcd2345

I am trying the following rule

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="IIS - Redirect Site (QA)" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.somethingelse.com/userToken={C:1}"  redirectType="Found"/>
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="token=([\w]+)" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

The rule tester is working as expected but the redirection is not happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Your rule only matches URLs like `https://www.something.com/?token=abcd2345`. So, the redirection indeed won't happen if the URL is  `https://www.something.com/token=abcd2345`. You can enable FRT to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

A query string is a set of characters tacked onto the end of a URL. The query string begins after the question mark `?` and can include one or more parameters. Each parameter is represented by a unique key-value pair or a set of two linked data items. An equals sign `=` separates each key and value, so the url you requested does not match the rewrite rule, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">   
  <match url="token=([\w]+)" />  
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.something.com" />        
    </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.somethingelse.com/userToken={R:1}" />  
</rule>
```